# Возможно ли слепить файл изображения из строки переданной в запросе?

Tags: java, android, node.js, fileupload

Из android-клиента, на сервер, передается файл в виде строки, на стороне андроид-приложения это делается как-то так:

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
}
model.setFileIcon(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Потом моделька отправляется в пост-запросе на сервер (с помощью Volley). В итоге, на бэке, у нас есть переменная в виде длиннючей строки, нужно как-то распознать mime-тип и положить содержимое в файл во временную папку с необходимым экстеншеном, ну и вообще проверить что это картинка а не что-то иное.

Как это сделать средствами NodeJS? (Давайте представим, что нет возможности изменить способ отправки файла в приложении, но если это необходимо сделать - предложите ваше решение).

Comment: а почему не передать mime в запросе?

Comment: Как я понимаю, вся проблема заключается только в том, что сервер не имеет тип файла до того, как ему оправили этот поток. Больше-то ничего не нужно. И если почему-то нельзя отослать сначала расширение (в Java, вроде бы, точно такой же метод split)? Ну тогда не знаю... У *.jpg два первых байта - FF D8, у *.png - 89 50.

Comment: @YuriyPo в android там что-то с uri, почему-то невозможно получить нормальное имя файла. По байтам учту как вариант) но все же надеюсь есть что-то поудобнее